# Informatica, need a lookup function without returning a value

Tags: informatica

I have a lookup table with 2 columns, and both are the key columns. The logic in the mapping transformation is to see if a table has both keys exist in this lookup table.

So, is there a lookup function that doesn't need to return anything. Similar to the EXIST in PL/SQL, or the lookup_match function in abinitio.

Comment: There is no transformations like this in infa. You can return a dummy value from lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Use a joiner - you can use both columns as keys, with nothing extra. Or does it have to be lookup for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Just build the SQL for the lookup so that it returns a dummy value like 'A' and in a subsequent Expression transformation, have an output port to check if the value is 'A' or null in order to determine if you found a match.

Your Lookup SQL Override might look like:

```
SELECT
COLUMN_A as COLUMN_A,
COLUMN_B as COLUMN_B,
'A' as MATCH_FLAG
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

With COLUMN_A and COLUMN_B being your lookup conditions and MATCH_FLAG being the returned column from the transformation.

Then your Expression output port might look like:

```
IIF(ISNULL(MATCH_FLAG),FALSE,TRUE)
```